# What does "the choice of open in the right" in Durrett's book mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading Rick Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples 5th Ed.
In [page 3 of the book](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf), Durrett says that the choice of “closed on the right” in $(a, b]$ is dictated by the fact that if $b_n \downarrow b$ then
we have
$$\bigcap_n (a, b_n] = (a, b].$$
And he says that the next definition will explain the choice of “open on the left.” The next definition is a definition of semialgebra (when I interpreted literary "next").

I have two questions;
1) what he did want to say "the choice of closed on the right"? Did he just want to say that you can write $(a, b]$ as an intersection of a half-open intervals?
2) Why "the next definition" gives the definition(meaning) of the choice open on the left?

A picture of the book in question:
[image]

Comment: I would say that it is not a method of intersections or how (a, b] was calculated. The set (a, b] is "open on the left because points arbitrarily close to a but larger than a are in the set but a is not.  In particular, if a< x< b then the open set (a, x) is a subset of (a, b].  And (a, b] is "closed on the right" because b **is** in the set. In particular if a< x< b then the closed set [x, b] is a subset of (a, b].

Answer (score 1):

To answer 1), I believe the "choice of closed on the right" is exactly what he meant to say (no words are being accidentally omitted!) and it is referring to the "half-open" in the name "half-open interval" describing $(a,b]$. Here, the half that is "closed" is at the $b$ endpoint (on the right) and the half that is "open" is at the $a$ endpoint (on the left). And the reason for the right vs the left comes from the assumption that the so-called Stieltjes measure function $F(x)$ (appearing in the theorem) is right-continuous, but not necessarily left-continuous (hence the downward limit $b_n\searrow b$).

Regarding 2) he is referring to the second part of the definition involving complements - if one half of the interval is closed, then in order to make complements work out the other half should be open. Indeed, if you tried to use closed intervals $[a,b]$ then the complement $(-\infty,a)\cup (b,\infty)$ could not be written as a finite union of closed intervals.

Comment: What did he want to claim after all?  I understand what you write.

Comment: There was no precise claim. It was just an illustration of how the right-continuity of the Stieltjes measure function naturally corresponds to a choice of half-open interval which is closed on the right.